# Latest logged in date mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The code is working and saving down last time a user logged in, but the problem is that I can't log in. It's loading for a short time when you trying to log in and then you still seeing the login view not the view you are supposed to see after(when login  succeeded).

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, ApplicationUser app)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            app = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.Email);
            app.Lastloggedin = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(app).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View(model);
        }
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
return View(model);
```

You are returning this in fact

```
return View("name of the current method/view", model);
```

And in your case:

```
return View("Login", model);
```

What you want to do is return the View that the user is supposed to see after logging in:

```
return View("/ViewThatRequiresLoggedInUser");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return View(model);
        }

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        ApplicationUser logged = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.Email);
        logged.Lastloggedin = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(logged).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Now it's working:)

Answer (score -1):

After validating the user has correct credentials, you should return / redirect to the signed-in model, not the login model.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        app = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.Email);
        app.Lastloggedin = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(app).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("SignedIn");
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more or write the correct code? I understand a little bit what you trying to tell me but can't see the correct code in my head:/